# How to send contents of groupbox to printer

Tags: vb.net, printing, groupbox

I have a groupbox that has some controls in it and i want to send it to printer.

I have this code thats builds the bmp file from the groupbox. How can i sent it to printer at button click?

```
Private Sub Doc_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
    Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.GroupBox1.Width, Me.GroupBox1.Height)
    Me.GroupBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.GroupBox1.Width, Me.GroupBox1.Height))
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(DirectCast(bmp, Image), x, y)
End Sub
```

I have in button click event:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim doc As New PrintDocument()
    doc = Doc_PrintPage()
    Dim dlgSettings As New PrintDialog()
    dlgSettings.Document = doc
    If dlgSettings.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        doc.Print()
    End If
End Sub
```

Final working code after advices:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BMP = New Bitmap(GroupBox1.Width, GroupBox1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    GroupBox1.DrawToBitmap(BMP, New Rectangle(0, 0, GroupBox1.Width, GroupBox1.Height))
    Dim pd As New PrintDocument
    Dim pdialog As New PrintDialog
    AddHandler pd.PrintPage, (Sub(s, args)
                                  args.Graphics.DrawImage(BMP, 0, 0)
                                  args.HasMorePages = False
                              End Sub)
    pdialog.ShowDialog()
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = pdialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
    pd.Print()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that you have a `PrintDocument` object, you call its `Print` method, it raises its `PrintPage` event, you handle that event and in the handler method you use GDI+ to draw whatever is to be printed.  So, you need to get rid of this line:

```
doc = Doc_PrintPage()
```

What could that possibly be doing?  You are trying to assign the result of a method to a `PrintDocument` variable.  In order for that to be meaningful, the method would have to return a `PrintDocument` object, which it doesn't.  What you need to do is register that method to handle the `PrintPage` event of your `PrintDocument`:

```
AddHandler doc.PrintPage, AddressOf Doc_PrintPage
```

If you do that then you need to remove the handler as well.  A better option would be to add all your printing objects to the form in the designer and then create a `PrintPage` event handler for the `PrintDocument` just as you would create event handlers for a `Button` or a `TextBox`.

For more info on printing, you may find [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?548579-A-beginner-s-guide-to-printing-in-NET) useful.

Comment: opened my eyes. useful link. final working code posted in question area.